# Multi Scenario Form Action (Background, Multiple Actions, Timer)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have tried using methods that may work for one scenario or another in **AJAX**, **Javascript**, **JQuery** and **PHP**, but I have not found a way to achieve the correct results for my scenarios.

I have a search box text input field as :

```
<input id="field" name="q" maxlength="2048" autocomplete="off" title="Search" type="text" value="" spellcheck="false" autofocus>
```

There are three scenarios in which different actions need to occur:

1. On page load, send the input to `search-api.php` as `POST` every 5 seconds in the background, and get results back from the action and set the response equal to `$url`. (Must not only show response for first submit, but also for all changes in input when updated every 5 seconds).
2. When enter button is pressed, send the input as `GET` to *https://externalaction.com/search* in foreground.
3. When button `<input class="button default" name="BtnX" type="submit" value="Search">` is pressed, send the input as `GET` to *https://externalaction.com/search* in foreground.

I know this is complicated but I have yet to find a solution that works for all three scenarios without interfering with each other, and no one online seems to have any information or questions quite like this situation.

Thank you to anyone who has any help, tips, or answers / code!

Comment: could you put some code about your javascript that you already working so far?

Comment: @Atmahadli I don't have any javascript in my page anymore, but here is a list of examples that I tested: http://pastebin.com/SffBEhXw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem too complicated, although I'm not sure why you'd want to send search queries every 5 seconds instead of on keypress? In any case it should just be using [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) and [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

```
<form action="https://externalaction.com/search" method="get">
    <input id="field" name="q" maxlength="2048" autocomplete="off" title="Search" type="text" value="" spellcheck="false" autofocus>
    <input class="button default" name="BtnX" type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<div id="results"></div>

<script>
$(function() {
    search();
});
function search() {
    $.post(
        "search-api.php",
        { field: $('#field').val() },
        function (data) {
            $('#results').html(data); // or whatever format you want data in
        }
    );

    setTimeout(search, 5000);
}
</script>
```

If you're interested in using keypress instead of every 5 seconds, it would be something like this for the JS:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#field').on('keyup change', 'search');
});
function search() {
    $.post(
        "search-api.php",
        { field: $('#field').val() },
        function (data) {
            $('#results').html(data); // or whatever format you want data in
        }
    );
}
</script>
```

Although in this case you don't need a named function, you could just make the `search()` function the keypress callback.

You also mentioned wanting to set the AJAX response to `$url`, however that *looks* like a PHP variable, so you wouldn't be able to modify that if it's in the page with the form unless you reloaded it. That's easy enough to do if you wanted to programmatically do a redirect, but would get pretty tricky and into weird loops. So it would be better to know what `$url` is being used for in the page, and then use JS to replace it with the value from the callback the same way I'm replacing the HTML of the results `div` in my current example.

The search form field will submit automatically on an 'enter' keypress as long as it has focus (i.e. after someone is finished typing in it and hits 'enter'), but if you want to send results whenever enter is pressed regardless of which input has focus [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40780651/2053165) will help.

As an aside, typically you don't want to recursively keep searching with a timeout without some kind of end condition which clears the timeout, as in some cases it can lead to memory issues.

Comment: It is sending the search query to an API in the background every 5 second to display relevant content in the search page as it is being entered, I may change the value from 5 to 1 later, but as a test, I will use 5 seconds.

Comment: @CarterRoeser in that case the above would work fine, as long as you format the returned results in `data` how you like.

Comment: I will test this and reply again soon if it works or not.

Comment: There is an error. Because of the line "{ field: $('#field').val() }" it breaks the opening parenthesis of "$.get(" and returns "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list". This error was generated both in Google Chrome itself and by http://www.jslint.com/.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should search input is a form and need form tag even if it's only one input. lets consider it like this:

as you set set button type to submit. the 2 and 3 options would work.

```
<form id="search-form" action="https://externalaction.com/search" method="GET">
<input id="field" name="q" maxlength="2048" autocomplete="off" title="Search" type="text" value="" spellcheck="false" autofocus>
    <input class="button default" name="BtnX" type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

second of all in case if in some situations (really rare) some browsers didn't work properly with `type="submit"` for enter button you should use jQuery like this one:

```
$(function() {
    $("#search-form input").keypress(function (e) {
        if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {
            $('#search-form button[type=submit] .default').click();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

for autocomplete search you can use many exist libraries or write it yourself I recommend to read this article for an example:

http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/ajax-search-suggest-wearehunted/

actually if you use a standard form element the only thing you are looking for is just a autocomplete search input which i believe users used to see result by typing each word instead every 5 second. but its up to you.

**Edited according to your last comment:**

if you have a single action for search you should at least use two different view.

to use autocomplete feature you should use ajax and if you want to have only one action or page just send an extra parameter and make a partial-view which echo result back in Json instead of a complete view which contains header and footer and ...

Comment: That doesn't help. As I stated in the question, I am able to accomplish all three tasks, just not all at the same time.

Comment: I don't get what does "at the same time" mean. do you mean do all with jQuery? (using jQuery to add a form element and put search input in it and submit by pressing enter button or clicking on search button ?)

Comment: I can currently make it so that the either the enter button works, or the search button works, or it autosubmits in the background, but when i try to accomplish all three in the same page, they interfere with each other and the actions fail.

Answer (score 0):

Function `searchData()` handle the AJAX request. `setInterval(function(){searchData()}, 5000)` section handle request search content every 5 second. If click on Enter key, then that request handle on keydown event, finally click function handle the request come through the search button.

search.php

```
<!--- Search field and button -->
<input id="field" name="q" maxlength="2048" autocomplete="off" title="Search" type="text" value="" spellcheck="false" autofocus> 
<input type="button" name="search" id="search" value="Search"/>

<!--- Display result -->
<span id="res"></span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e){
    // function used for AJAX call
    function searchData(){
        var txt = $("#field").val();
        $.get("searchData.php", {search: txt}, function(result){
            $("#res").html(result);
        });
    }   
    // search every 5 second
    setInterval(function(){searchData()}, 5000);
    // if press enter button search
    $('#field').on('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            searchData();
        }
    }); 
    // if search button press
    $("#search").click(function(){
        searchData();
    });     
});     
</script>
```

searchData.php - Page used to handle the request

```
<?php
    // testing purpose
    echo $_GET['search'];
?>
```

Comment: @CarterRoeser  Create two files in separate directory(not your actual project folder) and run above code, then you can understand how it is working. Then apply the concept to your actual project.